# Loops to create new variables in ddply

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr

I am using ddply to aggregate and summarize data frame variables, and I am interested in looping through my data frame's list to create the new variables.

```
new.data <- ddply(old.data, 
                  c("factor", "factor2"),
                  function(df)
                    c(a11_a10 = CustomFunction(df$a11_a10),
                      a12_a11 = CustomFunction(df$a12_a11),
                      a13_a12 = CustomFunction(df$a13_a12),
                      ...
                      ...
                      ...))
```

Is there a way for me to insert a loop in ddply so that I can avoid writing each new summary variable out, e.g.

```
for (i in 11:n) {
  paste("a", i, "_a", i - 1) = CustomFunction(..... )
}
```

I know that this is not how it would actually be done, but I just wanted to show how I'd conceptualize it. Is there a way to do this in the function I call in ddply, or via a list?

**UPDATE:** Because I'm a new user, I can't post an answer to my own question:

My answer involves ideas from Nick's answer and Ista's comment:

```
func <- function(old.data, min, max, gap) {
  varrange <- min:max
  usenames <- paste("a", varrange, "_a", varrange - gap, sep="")
  new.data <- ddply(old.data,
                    .(factor, factor2),
                    colwise(CustomFunction, c(usenames)))
}
```

Comment: you are probably after `transform()` or `summarize()`. the help page for `summarize` shows some good examples.

Comment: @Chase - Re: summarize, I could do for (i in 11:n) with(old.data, summarize(old.data[, paste("a", i, "_a", i - 1, sep="")], llist(factor, factor2), CustomFunction))

Comment: If you had made your example reproducible it would have made life easier for your potential helpers. In the absense of a working example, I can only guess that you are looking for `?colwise` (see the examples for use with ddply).

Comment: @ Ista - Thanks, colwise was exactly what I was looking for, after learning of Nick's initial loading of variable names into memory.

Comment: +1 @Casey. extremely elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on the excellent answer by @Nick, here is one approach to the problem

```
foo <- function(df){
  names   = paste("a", 11:n, "_a", 10:(n-1), sep = "")
  results = sapply(df[,names], CustomFunction)
}

new.data = ldply(dlply(old.data, c("factor", "factor2")), foo)
```

Here is an example application using the `tips` dataset in `ggplot2`. Suppose we want to calculate the average of `tip` and `total_bill` by combination of `sex` and `smoker`, here is how the code would work

```
foo = function(df){names = c("tip", "total_bill"); sapply(df[,names], mean)}
new = ldply(dlply(tips, c("sex", "smoker")), foo)
```

It produces the output shown below

```
         .id      tip total_bill
1  Female.No 2.773519   18.10519
2 Female.Yes 2.931515   17.97788
3    Male.No 3.113402   19.79124
4   Male.Yes 3.051167   22.28450
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @ Ramnath- This is exactly what I am looking for EXCEPT I'd like the factor/ID variables to stay separated. I believe the answer I gave in my update will allow me to do this, but you neatly answered my question and made the example into a function that I will try to adapt. Thanks.

Comment: @Casey. Your answer is more elegant!! I upvoted it and would have given it +2 if I could have. Nice work

Comment: And all of this can be done in one line using `colwise`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you essentially want to apply a custom function to every column in the `ddply` data.frame.

The good news is there is a `ddply` function that does exactly that.  This means the solution to your problem boils down to a one liner:

Building on the excellent example of @Ramnath:

```
library(ggplot2)
customfunction <- mean
ddply(tips, .(sex, smoker), numcolwise(customfunction))

     sex smoker total_bill      tip     size
1 Female     No   18.10519 2.773519 2.592593
2 Female    Yes   17.97788 2.931515 2.242424
3   Male     No   19.79124 3.113402 2.711340
4   Male    Yes   22.28450 3.051167 2.500000
```

The reason this works is that `colwise` turns a function that works on a vector into a function that works on a column in a data.frame.  There are two variants of `colwise`: `numcolwise` works only on numeric columns, and `catcolwise` works on categorical columns.  See`?colwise` for more information.

*EDIT:*

I appreciate that you may not wish to apply the function to *all* columns in your data.frame.  Still, I find this syntax so easy, that my general approach would be to modify the data.frame that I pass to `ddply`.  For example, the following modified example subsets `tips` to exclude some columns.  The solution is still a one-liner:

```
ddply(tips[, -2], .(sex, smoker), numcolwise(customfunction))

     sex smoker total_bill     size
1 Female     No   18.10519 2.592593
2 Female    Yes   17.97788 2.242424
3   Male     No   19.79124 2.711340
4   Male    Yes   22.28450 2.500000
```

Comment: this works only if you are applying the function to all the columns other than those used for the split. If that is indeed the case for the OP then this would be the best solution. Else, I think the solution proposed by the OP is more general.

Comment: @Ramnath, Agreed, and good point.  Still, in my workflow I would prefer to do a simple subset of the data.frame rather than a somewhat complicated bit of coding.  I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: colwise has a `cols` argument which accepts a character vector of variable names...

Answer (score 3):

In steps:

```
varrange<-11:n
usenames<-paste("a", varrange, "_a", varrange - 1, sep="")
results<-sapply(usenames, function(curname){CustomFunction(df[,curname])})
names(results)<-usenames
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks for your response, but it is not what I am looking for. I do wish to end up with a data frame that includes unique observations per each combination of "factor" and "factor2", and the output from my CustomFunction for each of my "a" variables for each unique combo of my two factors.

Comment: basically I am looking for the ddply functionality, but automating the variable creation using a loop or list approach.