# Evaluating ddply within a function when passed ggplot2 aesthetic mappings as arguments

Tags: r, plyr

I'm working on a function to create bean plots in ggplot2 and am stuck on the step calculating medians for each group.  I've tried a couple of the solutions at [Object not found error with ddply inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955128/object-not-found-error-with-ddply-inside-a-function) and [Object not found error with ddply inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955128/object-not-found-error-with-ddply-inside-a-function/6957340#6957340) but was still unable to get it to work.  The error message returned is `"Error in as.quoted(.variables) : object 'iv' not found"` which indicates it's not evaluting the
symbol `iv` in the correct environment. If possible, I would like to keep the method of passing the variables to the function with ggplot2 aesthetic mapping since
I will be using the same aesthetic mappings for the violin and rug plots later on in the function.

#### The code for the function:

```
 ggbean <- function(data = NULL, mapping = NULL, ...){
  require(plyr)

  x <- mapping[['x']]
  y <- mapping[['y']]

# Calculate medians for each group
 medFn <- function(mydat, x1, y1){
    z <- do.call("ddply",list(mydat, x1, summarize, med = call("median", y1, na.rm=TRUE)))
    return(z)
 }

res <- medFn(data, x, y)

}
```

#### Sample data

```
set.seed(1234)
single_df <- data.frame(dv = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100,12,3)), 
iv = as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 200, replace = TRUE)))
```

#### Call to function with ggplot2 aesthetics

```
res3 <- ggbean(data = single_df, aes(x = iv, y = dv))
```

should provide something like

```
  iv      med
  1  A 7.254916
  2  B 1.367827
  3  C 1.467737
  4  D 8.670698
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find life easier if you "render" the aesthetics early on.  Then you don't need any special ddply calls:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

ggbean <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  df <- quickdf(eval.quoted(mapping, data))
  ddply(df, "x", summarise, med = median(y, na.rm = TRUE))
}

single_df <- data.frame(
  dv = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 12, 3)), 
  iv = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 200, replace = TRUE)
)

res3 <- ggbean(data = single_df, aes(x = iv, y = dv))
```