# ddply gives an error message (object '...' not found) when I try to create that object

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to create a summary of my data with the ddply function. 
Now this has worked before, so I am really confused, I didn't change anything in the code (afaik), but this is what I put in:

```
desc_df <- ddply(df, c("Condition", "stimCat"), summarise,
           N    = length(RT),
           mean = mean(RT),
           sd   = sd(RT),
           se   = sd / sqrt(N))
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
Error in -------------------------------desc_df <- ddply(df, c("Condition",  : 
object 'desc_df' not found
```

This is what comes out when I give the input without 'desc_df <-'

```
   Condition stimCat     N       mean        sd         se
1         NA      NA -1080  -846.9602 -502.1748 -15.280694
2         NA      NA -2160  -871.5088 -542.4716 -11.672131
3         NA      NA -3240  -818.8568 -526.7179  -9.253491
```

and some more lines in the same fashion

This is what I found close to this: 
[Object not found error with ddply inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955128/object-not-found-error-with-ddply-inside-a-function)
but it doesn't help or I don't understand it right. 
Jorens answer (answered Aug 5 '11 at 13:47) says something about problems with ddply and summarize, but I am not sure it has something to do with creating an object. (I cant tell though, as I am pretty new to R)

How can I create that object with the summary in it, without getting an error.

Thank you for your help!

With the help from the comments I was able to create what I needed in this way: I used the code from zx8754 which was using the mtcars dataset. 
It worked. 
Now I exchanged every part in his code with the names in mine. 
It worked.

So it looks like this

```
    desc_df <- ddply(df, c("Condition", "stimCat"), summarise,
           N    = length(RT),
           mean = mean(RT),
           sd   = sd(RT),
           se   = sd / sqrt(N))

    desc_df <- ddply(df, c("Condition", "stimCat"), summarise, 
              N = length(RT), 
              mean = mean(RT), 
              sd = sd(RT), 
              se = sd / sqrt(N))
```

The first version creates an error, the second doesnt. But no matter how much I try to find differences, I cant...

When I do

```
dput(head(df))
```

I get:

```
structure(list(Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Goal", "Plan"), class = "factor"), Target = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("emptRectangle", "emptTriangle"
), class = "factor"), Subject = structure(c(101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
"52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", 
"63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", 
"74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", 
"85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", 
"96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", 
"106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", 
"115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", 
"124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", 
"133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138"), class = "factor"), 
    Block = c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105), Filling = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("empt", "fill"), class = "factor"), 
    Shape = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Rectangle", 
    "Triangle"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(2L, NA, 
    NA, 2L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("L", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    Stimulus = structure(c(9L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("emptRectangle", 
    "emptRectangleL", "emptRectangleW", "emptTriangle", "emptTriangleL", 
    "emptTriangleW", "fillRectangle", "fillRectangleL", "fillRectangleW", 
    "fillTriangle", "fillTriangleL", "fillTriangleW"), class = "factor"), 
    Response = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), RT = c(2036, 713, 690, 995, 
    667, 5137), stimCat = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Target", 
    "SsR", "SsRd", "SdR", "SdRd"), class = "factor"), logRT = c(7.61874237767041, 
    6.5694814204143, 6.5366915975913, 6.90274273715859, 6.50279004591562, 
    8.54422453046727), outlier = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("Condition", 
"Target", "Subject", "Block", "Filling", "Shape", "Type", "Stimulus", 
"Response", "RT", "stimCat", "logRT", "outlier"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: what happens if you execute without the `desc_df <- `?

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you, I tried to improve it once more. I cant create a reproducible example though, I have no idea how to create a dataset and such... sorry.

Comment: @drmariod It gives me a dataframe, but that dataframe gives NAs in Condition which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your code works fine with an example dataframe, see `myResult <- ddply(mtcars, c("cyl", "gear"), summarise,
                  N    = length(mpg),
                  mean = mean(mpg),
                  sd   = sd(mpg),
                  se   = sd / sqrt(N))`

Comment: You could provide something like `put(head(df))`.

Comment: @zx8754 that works for me too, that is so weird... could it have anything to do with the classes?

Comment: @drmariod what do you mean by that? i tried that code but it doesnt know 'put', I cant find it in the help either

Comment: sorry, `dput`, (stupid auto correction)

Comment: ok, this is the weirdest thing: 
I used your code @zx8754, exchanged every part with the names in my dataset and it worked. The weirdest thing: the upper creates an error, the lower doesnt.
`desc_df <- ddply(df, c("Condition", "stimCat"), summarise,
               N    = length(RT),
               mean = mean(RT),
               sd   = sd(RT),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N))
  
desc_df <- ddply(df, c("Condition", "stimCat"), summarise, 
                  N = length(RT), 
                  mean = mean(RT), 
                  sd = sd(RT), 
                  se = sd / sqrt(N))`

Comment: Ok, this has worked and I am able to continue. 
As there was no real 'solution' in the sense of something one could make sense of, what do I do? Close the question?